# Issues with django rest framework using dynamic serializer

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, dynamic-class

I'm have a dynamic dataset I am trying to use with the Django REST Framework by dynamically creating serializer, but it doesn't seem to process the dynamic attributes I add.

Here is the code:

```
-- views.py
class DynamicReadings(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        site = self.kwargs['site']
        devices = Device.objects.filter(reader__site__slug=site).order_by('code')
        dyn_fields = ['x%s' % a.code for a in devices]
        return SerializerClassFactory(dyn_fields)

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...
        # the query is correct and returns data

-- serializers.py
def SerializerClassFactory(dyn_fields):
class DynamicSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    read_at = serializers.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('read_at')

    for f in dyn_fields:
        setattr(DynamicSerializer, f, serializers.FloatField())
    DynamicSerializer.Meta.fields += ','.join("'%s'" % f for f in dyn_fields)

    return DynamicSerializer
```

When I execute the code, only the attribute (read_at) specified in the class definition is serialized.  None of the dynamic attributes appear to be working.

Example:

[{"read_at":"2017-05-07T00:12:29Z"},{"read_at":"2017-05-08T00:12:30Z"}]

Here is the output of the class after creation in shell:

```
>>> serializer = SerializerClassFactory(['x01', 'x02', 'x03'])
>>> serializer.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': 'xxx.api.serializers', 
'Meta': <class 'xxx.api.serializers.SerializerClassFactory.<locals>.DynamicSerializer.Meta'>, 
'x02': FloatField(), '_declared_fields': OrderedDict([('read_at', DateTimeField())]), 
'__doc__': None, 'x01': FloatField(), 'x03': FloatField()})
```

Additionally, I've tried:

```
setattr(DynamicSerializer, f, property(serializers.FloatField()))
setattr(DynamicSerializer, f, type(serializers.FloatField()))
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, only the fields are dynamic, the base serializer is the same. In order to make it work, we will change only the fields on the `DynamicSerializer`

in `serializers.py` you would have:

```
class DynamicSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    read_at = serializers.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('read_at')

    def __init__(*args, dyn_fields=None, **kwargs):
        dyn_fields = dyn_fields or []
        for field in dyn_fields:
            self.fields[field] = serializers.FloatField()

        super(DynamicSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and in the `views.py` on the `get_serializer_class` method you would `return DynamicSerializer(dyn_fields=dyn_fields)`

for more info visit http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields

Comment: I had to change the signature of the __init__ method:  def __init__(self, dyn_fields=None, *args, **kwargs).  Now I am getting the error 'DynamicSerializer' object is not callable.

Comment: You are getting this issue because not overriding `get_serializer_class` is what you need. Take a look here https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L105-L130
`get_serializer_class` expects to return a class (a callable), not an instance. You should override `get_serializer()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and pointing me in the right direction.  In this case, you can't use positional arguments as it causes issues.  See here [link](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/4397)

Comment: `class DynamicSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        read_at = serializers.DateTimeField()
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            dyn_fields = kwargs.pop('dyn_fields')
            for field in dyn_fields:
                self.fields[field] = serializers.FloatField()
            super(DynamicSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: `def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        site = self.kwargs['site']
        device = Device.objects.filter(reader__site__slug=site).order_by('code')
        dyn_fields = ['x%s' % a.code for a in devices]
        kwargs['dyn_fields'] = dyn_fields
        return DynamicSerializer(*args, **kwargs)`